# homework - iterative to recursive method

Tags: java, recursion

My teacher has asked Us to create two methods that determine if a string is a palindrome.
One has to be a recursive method and the other an iterative method, Ive figured out the iterative version but I dont know how to go about making it a recursive method.
Any and all help is welcomed. Thank you

```
static boolean isPalindrome(String s)
{
    String noSpaces = s.replaceAll("\\W", ""); //remove all non-word chars from string
    String revString = ""; //store reversed string 

    //for loop working from outter chars to inner
    //to reverse the string

    for(int i = 1; i <= noSpaces.length(); i++)
    {
        //if true add char to revString String 
        if(noSpaces.charAt(i - 1) == noSpaces.charAt(noSpaces.length() - i))
            revString = revString + noSpaces.charAt(i - 1);
    }

    //return true if original string matches reversed string
    if(noSpaces.equals(revString))
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

Comment: You might want to check your string in all Upper or Lower case. `noSpaces = noSpaces.toLowerCase();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion works by a method calling itself. A famous example of recursion is factorials: `n! = n * (n-1)!`. Recursion works because the input changes each time; if it didn't, it would basically be an infinite loop taking up memory and eventually crashing the program. The last thing about recursion: there is some point that the answer is known, like for factorials, `0! = 1`. A recursive method needs to give an answer for this known value or it will continue until it crashes or throw an error (because of an impossible thing being asked). In you example, you know if something is a palindrome if it has one char or two chars that are exactly the same.

Recursion: The method you would want is to take a String, do the replaceAll to remove non-word chars, **(add a .toLowerCase() to it)**, and than check the first and last chars to see if they are the same. If they are, then run the method again with the input being `noSpaces` with the first and last chars removed. However, if the length of the String is <= 3 and the first and last chars are the same, then you can go ahead and return true. If you don't add that, you will get an error when you try to remove non-existing chars (there is another way of doing it though).

Your iterative method is big, you could slim it way down. You don't need to check all the chars, only half of them (if you have on odd length, then 1/2 + 1). You also don't need to make a copy of the String, instead, use two charAt methods on the same String.

**Edit:** I did remove my code because this is homework. If you really need to look at it, look at the edit history

Answer (score 1):

Make a recursive method that takes a string and returns a boolean like the iterative method.

- It will check the first and last characters, if they are different return `false`,
- If they are the same call and return the method with the first and last characters taken off as the argument
- If it is a single character or the empty string it will return `true`.

Tips on your iterative method:

- Does case sensitivity matter?
- While you method is one way of doing it, there is another way that only needs to check half the string (not from `1` to `noSpaces.length()`).

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
public static boolean palindrome(String Str){
        if(Str.length()<=0)
            return true;
        if(Str.charAt(0)!=Str.charAt(Str.length()-1))
            return false;
        else
            return palindrome(Str.substring(1,Str.length()-1));
    }
```